# Change every first word color in li with javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I have list of links, and I need to change every first word color or just add html tag with class.

My code is:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">example one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">example two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">example tree</a></li>
</ul>
```

For example every word "example" in list need to be red color.

Comment: can't you just edit the html?

Comment: Side-note about the "duplicate" vote: While that question is about making the "first" word bold, instead of coloring it, the idea is the same. Changing the applied styles should be a trivial modification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .firstWord{
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Hello world</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Hello world</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Hello world</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Hello world</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>

<script>
    $('li a').each(function(){

    var text = $(this).text().split(' ');
    if(text.length < 2)
        return;

    text[0] = '<span class="firstWord">'+text[0]+'</span>';

    $(this).html( text.join(' ') );

});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello i know that but i need the javascript will add auto <span> every first word.

Comment: user3765096 thanks a lot this is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Css for That. 
or you can use javascript like this

Html :

```
<ul list style type = "none">
  <li id = "l0">this is line one</li>
  <li id = "l1">this is line two</li>
  <li id = "l2">this is line three</li>
</ul>
```

javascript :

```
function highlight(name,color) {
  var a = document.getElementById(name);
  a.style.color = color;
}

highlight("l0", "red");
highlight("l2", "blue");
```

Comment: This doesn't work though.

Comment: This styles more than just the first words the OP wants to style.

Comment: This doesn't work for me